# how can i render table inside table by their associated id in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

hey i want to render sub_task table inside task table by their associated id. currently i am able to render all sub_task inside different task.

projects_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @project = Project.includes(stages: :tasks).find(params[:id])
    @stages = @project.stages
    @sub_tasks = SubTask.all
  end
```

routes.rb

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :stages do
      resources :tasks do
        resources :sub_tasks
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def show
  @project = Project.includes({stages: {tasks: :sub_tasks}}).find(params[:id])
  @stages = @project.stages
  @sub_tasks = SubTask.all
end
```

This should do the job